# Comment traduire "laxly regulated regime"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comment peut-on traduire en français l'expression *"laxly regulated regime"*?

Comme dans la phrase :

> Firms should not follow laws blindly in *laxly regulated regimes*.

La meilleure traduction que j'arrive faire est :

> Les entreprises ne devraient pas toujours suivre les lois dans des *juridictions avec des régulations insuffisantes*.

Mais je ne suis pas sûr que "insuffisant" est le bon mot ici...

Comment: Bear in mind that  the English sentence is not standard (business or legal) English. It is translated from another language, most likely. In English, there are no //laws "in regimes"//. Unless by regimes is meant political regimes but it still is nonsense. That said, you can have a /loosely regulated legal regime/.

Answer (score 4):

If by “laxly regulated regime” you want to clearly describe a place where the **enforcement** of (sufficient) existing  laws/regulations is lax than you might consider:

> “Les entreprises ne devraient pas toujours suivre les lois/règles dans
>   les juridictions/régimes/pays où les lois/réglementations sont
>   appliquées de manière/façon laxiste.”

If, however, you mean that the place is/has been lax in putting a sufficient number of laws/regs on the books [with or without  clearly addressing how they are enforced] I think either of the other two answers given so far would work (and perhaps you could consider the following as well) :

> “Les entreprises ne devraient pas toujours suivre les lois/règles dans
>   les juridictions/régimes/pays avec un système de réglementation [et
>   d'application  des normes/règles] laxiste/s.”

Answer (score 2):

*Laxly* est un adverbe venant de l'adjectif *lax*.

*Lax* peut se traduire par laxiste, et c'est je pense une des traductions possibles dans le contexte. Le problème avec votre traduction est qu'*insuffisant* ne transmet pas l'idée derrière le manque. Car s'il y a un manque, ce n'est pas dans la quantité, mais dans la souplesse (un surplus selon votre citation), ce qui n'est pas ressenti dans votre traduction. On perdrait donc de l'information.

On dirait donc plutôt une juridiction laxiste ou trop souple, mais pas insuffisante

Answer (score 1):

Below are two possible ways of saying it :

1. Les entreprises ne doivent pas suivre les lois aveuglément dans les régimes faiblement réglementés.
2. Les entreprises ne doivent pas suivre les lois à l'aveuglette dans les régimes faiblement réglementés.